# Uso Google Re2 en angular

Tags: angular, regex, sonarqube

Estoy haciendo un formulario donde valido el formato del telefono y el mail con regexp y sonarqube me rebota por riesgo de seguridad y al ver como se soluciona este problema me dice:

> Recommended Secure Coding Practices
> Check whether your regular expression engine (the algorithm executing your regular expression) has any known vulnerabilities. Search for vulnerability reports mentioning the one engine you're are using.
> Use if possible a library which is not vulnerable to Redos Attacks such as Google Re2.
> Remember also that a ReDos attack is possible if a user-provided regular expression is executed. This rule won't detect this kind of injection."

Pero no estoy consiguiendo que un proyecto de pruebas me testie correctamente la regexp del telefono:
en un compnente hago esto

```
import * as RE2 from 're2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'proyect';

  testRegExp(){

    let re2 = new RE2("^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$");
    var re2_res = re2.exec('algien@mail.com');
    alert(re2_res)
  }


}
```

y al hacer ng serve me tira estos errores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Tienen algun paso a paso para instalar y usar esta liberira en Angular 12? ¿me falto instalar algo mas ademas del re2?

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Es una recomendación, que se puede ignorar, pero ¿cuál de todos los problemas querés resolver? ¿Entender por qué aparece? ¿Ignorarla? ¿Ver si tu regex es realmente un riesgo o no? ¿Cómo instalar re2? ¿Cómo usarlo? ¿Cómo solucionar tu problema puntual con el módulo? Te recomendaría elegir sólo 1 de estas preguntas y dar el detalle completo de tu problema sobre la que elijas

Comment: Hola @Pollo, lo que quisiera resolver es **el uso de la librería de Google re2**, ya que no logre hacer que funcione, si bien logre engañar a sonar con RegExp en un string entiendo que no es lo mejor además de que da mucha mas ayuda esta liberaría que un String...
Así que concretamente necesito poder instalar y usar la librería que recomienda Sonar (Google Re2) el tema del data type Buffer ya esta, pero, me salió otro problema con una ruta por eso para no estar preguntando con cada problema pido un tuto paso a paso de como lograron hacer que funcione, creo que va ser lo mas fácil